# How to drag and drop form element contents

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I have a table with form elements (inputs, selects etc.)
I want to **copy** the content (or part of content) from one field to another: ex: '*flowers*' from row 4 to row 6.
How to preceed to drag the content and NOT the whole element?

This examplel will drag **the entire *input* element** using jQuery ui:

html:

```
<input type="text" />
```

jQuery:

```
$("input").draggable({
    cancel: null    
});
```

but I have no clue if there is a possibility to drag/drop the content (or value)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use helper method of jquery draggable.
In that helper method get the dragable control ..
From that controll get the value of the control and set it as hellper value.
on dropping get that value from like it was available in like  ui.helper

```
 $(dragableSelector).draggable({
            scroll: false,
            appendTo: "body",
            cursor: "move",
            cursorAt: { top: 5, left: -20 },
             helper: function (event) {
                //your intput conrol
var ctrl = $(this);
//get value from control
var val = ctrl.attr('val');
//wrap it in div soo you can see on dragging.
var div = $("<div style='z-index:9999;position:absolute;overflow:auto;' >"+val+ 
"</div>");
```

and in you droping section you need to do some thing like this.

```
$(dropableElementSelector).droppable({
  drop: function (event, ui) {
   //your desire value is
  var desireval =$(ui.helper).html();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You opened my mind @Bilal lilla. Is it also possible to COPY instead of just MOVING. How do you get the value into the field (here: desireval). Can I use the CTRL-button to deside whether I want to insert into or replace the text? Thank you again!!